# Steps to create separate Sign In for user and admin rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to create separate sign in form for user and the admin in ruby on rails 4.2.Where when we click on the link for example(clicking admin login it should be directed to the admin page)

Comment: Do you actually want them to go to a separate login view, or is this really a question about authorization and/or authentication? Are you using a library such as Devise for your logins, or have you rolled your own?

Comment: @RalphKing I have used bycrpt gem and not used devise gem for login